# Указатели на строки в си

Tags: c, строки, указатели

Здравствуйте! Начал изучать си, но проблема с указателям.  Что значит данный код?

```
char *name = "Vasya";
printf("%s", name);
```

Почему указатель хранит строку? По сути указатель предназначен для хранения других адресов

```
char *a = NULL;
char b = 1;

a = &b;
```

Но никак не строку.  Разъясните пожалуйста

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если у вас есть символьный массив, как, например,

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

то имя массива в выражениях за редким исключением, как, например, при использовании с оператором `sizeof` , неявно преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент.

Поэтому вы можете написать

```
char *p = s;
```

В результате указатель `p` получит адрес первого элемента массива `s`, то есть будет указывать на букву `'H'`.

Вы могли бы получить тот же самый результат, записав

```
char *p = &s[0];
```

В этом предложении

```
char *name = "Vasya";
```

происходят две вещи. Во-первых, в статической памяти создается безыменный символьный массив, содержащий символы строкового литерала. Во-вторых, определяется указатель `name` , который указывает на первый символ этого массива.

Вы можете представить это следующим образом

```
char unnamed[6] = { 'V'. 'a', 's', 'y', 'a', '\0' };
char *name = unnamed;
```

или

```
char *name = &unnamed[0];
```

То есть в любом случае указатель не хранит строку, а указывает на первый символ строки, которая может представлять собой массив, объявленный пользователем, либо строковый литерал, для которого компилятор сам создает массив для его хранения.

Имейте в виду, что строковые литералы в С++ в отличии от C имеют типы константных символьных массивов. Поэтому в C++ правильно будет записать

```
const char *name = "Vasya";
```

Также обратите внимание, что ни в C, ни в C++ вы не можете изменять строковые литералы. Любая попытка изменить строковый литерал ведет к неопределенному поведению программы. Например, следующий код ошибочен

```
char *name = "Vasya";
name[0] = 'T';
```

Но вы можете объявить массив и инициализировать его символами строкового литерала. Тогда вы можете изменить элементы этого массива, если, кончено, вы не объявите этот массив как константный.

```
char name[] = "Vasya";
name[0] = 'T';
```

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, в чём разница между `char *name = "Vasya";` и `char name[] = "vasya";` ?

Comment: @ast В первом случае создается указатель на строковый литерал, который, то есть строковый литерал, используя этот указатель,  изменять нельзя. Во втором случае создается массив, который инициализируется символами строкового литерала, и который можно изменять.

Comment: `char *name[] = "vasya";`

а это получается указатель на массив? можно ли его изменять?

Comment: @ast char *name[] = "vasya";  это неверная запись. Правильно будет записать char *name[] = { "vasya" }; В этом случае создается массив указателей из одного элемента, который будет содержать адрес первого символы строкового литерала  "vasya"

Comment: я понял, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 4):

Строка `"Vasya"` - это т.наз. *строковый литерал*. Это самостоятельный безымянный объект типа "массив" (тип `char [6]`), живущий в статической памяти. Он является lvalue, т.е. имеет конкретное положение в памяти.

Ваш указатель `name` не "хранит строку". Строка хранится сама по себе, отдельно, как массив в статической памяти. А ваш указатель просто указывает на нулевой элемент этого массива. То есть, как вы и ожидали, он хранит именно *адрес* - адрес нулевого элемента этого массива.

Другими словами, если дать этому строковому литералу какое-то условное внутренне синтетическое имя, то ваше объявление будет эквивалентно такому

```
static char _literal_Vasya[6] = { 'V', 'a', 's', 'y', 'a', 0 };
char *name = _literal_Vasya; // = &_literal_Vasya[0]
```

с той только разницей, что строковый литерал является *немодифицируемым* объектом (несмотря на то, что его тип в С не является const-квалифицированным). Поэтому указывать на него лучше, как на константный объект

```
const char *name = "Vasya";
```

---

Строковый литерал, как было сказано выше, является самостоятельным объектом типа "массив" и ведет он себя точно так же, как и любой другой объекта типа "массив". Он точно так же неявно приводится к типу "указатель", как и любой другой массив в С и, соответственно, ведет себя точно также с операторами `sizeof`, `[]`, `+` и т.п.

```
size_t s = sizeof("Vasya"); // 6
char c1 = "Vasya"[3];       // 'y'
char c2 = 1["Vasya"];       // 'a'
char c3 = *"Vasya";         // 'V'
char *p1 = "Vasya" + 2;     // указатель на 's'
char (*p2)[6] = &"Vasya";   // указатель на весь массив
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Answer (score 3):

Указатель хранит адрес первого символа в строке.

Маркером конца строки является байт равный 0.

Из этого следует, например, что определение длины строки стоит дорого - надо пробежать по всей строке и сравнить все ее символы с 0.